# Show menu after video ends

Tags: ios, css, html, flash, video

1) Visit the following link:
http://pericles.webcity.com.au/~mer19867/enrolment/

2) The intro video will play automatically. Once it ends, a blue menu appears.

3) The video is in flash and I am not sure if the blue menu is part of it or not.

4) Currently the video is not accessible on iPhone and iPad because it is flash.

5) My client wants me to convert it to html5.

6) I downloaded SWF (blue menu was not part of it). I converted the SWF to MP4 and emedded in html5 using the video tag.

7) How do I make the blue menu appear once the video ends, like it does now.

NOTE: I did not develop this website so I don't know much. Please make the best assumptions you can and guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a listener to the video so you'll know when it has finished playing, then you can show a div with your menu on top of the video.

I've set up a jsfiddle with a demo video to show how it works - [see the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/grantgibson/eB8Hg/1/). (Note: the video runs for approx 10-15 seconds, then the menu will automatically appear.

*Update:* Now including code to make the system responsive following the OP's comment.

Here's the javascript:

```
var video = document.getElementById("myvideo");   
var menu = document.getElementById("endframe");

function init() {   
    video.onended = function(e) {
        menu.style.height = video.clientHeight + "px";
        menu.style.display = "block";
    } 
}
init();

window.onresize = function() {
    menu.style.height = video.clientHeight + "px";
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <video controls autoplay id="myvideo">
      <source type="video/mp4" src="YOUR_VIDEO.mp4"/>
     </video>
    <div id="endframe">
        <h1>Menu</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. But the div containing menu has been positioned with absolute values. How would it work across platforms including mobile devices. In my case, the menu has to appear between the video and has to be that position no matter what the platform and screen size is. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, no problem. The position:absolute is only within its container (position:relative), not absolute to the screen so it'll still work with other content around it. I've updated my demo to show that. I've also updated the CSS to show it working responsively, and added a line of JS to match the menu height to the (unpredictable) height of the video. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you once again. I rally appreciate your effort. I will be implementing your method soon and let you know if I find success. Keeps up the good work. :)

Comment: That's great.  Please consider marking this question as answered if you're happy with the solution.

Comment: Oh I will surely mark it as answered once i implement your method on my file. I am new here and just don't want to loose contact with you, maybe i will run into some obstacle. I will update here asap. thanks for all the help till now.